# whea_uncorrectable_error when playing games

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I'm a brainlet with computers so if I've omitted obviously necessary information I'm sorry and I will add whatever comments recommend, that being said I've been running into WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR 124 today whenever playing games for about 10-15 minutes, and I'm unsure why.

!analyze -v of memory.dmp: https://pastebin.com/9b2C4v3b

EDIT: I ran some diagnostics, I used Furmark, Prime95 and coretemp and kept an eye on stuff. I used both small FFT and large FFT on Prime95 and nothing went wrong with any of these tests and both cpu and gpu maxed out at around 70C which as far as I know is fine, so I'm really confused what could be causing this especially since it only seems to happen during games. Could this be PSU related?

Comment: Is your PC overheating?

Comment: I'm.. not sure, is there any software you recommend that I can use to investigate that?

Comment: I use [SpeedFan - Access temperature sensor in your computer](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php)

Comment: Looks like Discord caused a memory error in bank 0

Comment: @Ramhound it bsod'd again with System where discord was

Comment: @DavidPostill howdy, I've updated the information in this a bit could I get your opinion on what this could be given the new info? I'm a bit confused..

Comment: @Phase - Based on the dump, same as my previous comment suggested, it appears you have a memory hardware failure

Comment: does bank 0 mean the 0th position RAM? I'm not really familiar with terminology

Comment: Also sorry to bother you but could I ask for what implies this? I'm not doubting I'm just curious to know more about what's going on, is it the 0000'00.. etc in the final line of the stack?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/U4Wq63kY This was the most recent bsod from just now, does this also suggest the same?

Comment: Ok sorry to spam comments but I just remembered, I did the windows memory diagnostics before asking this and it didn't return any errors so idk if that means it may be something else? Or maybe the tool is just bad idk